# SharePoint 2013 - Document Library visibility

Tags: sharepoint-server, document-library

Is it possible to hide a Document Library in SharePoint for other Users, so that the Site Owner can only see the Library.

Are there any solutions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can break permission inheritance on the library settings.

Then remove all users from the permission list. Add Site Owner group.

Comment: This sounds good. But I have another question (Site Owner). We have a workgroup in our company an for each workgroup a teamsite, there has everyone a subsite with document libs. So is it possible for the users to make a own permission for the doc libs?

Comment: Please rephrase question.